# When I load a aspx page in IFRAME, The content of the page always warped into <PRE> tag How to solve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I load a aspx page in IFRAME, The content of the page always warped into tag How to solve this?

Because of this Website shows the html code of the page that load in IFRAME.

But when I load a html page it works fine.

Here is the code,

```
<iframe
    id="frameNews"
    name="framePressRelease"
    runat="server"
    class="iframe" 
    src="PressRelease.aspx" frameborder="0" 
    marginwidth="0"
    marginheight="0"
    scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Please help me,

Thank you,
Ravi.

Comment: You have a trailing `</code>` element. Is there an opening `<code>` tag? What do you mean by "wrapped in <pre>"?

Comment: No. I was mistakenly added to the question the </code> tag. I'll remove it. Thank you.

Comment: Mistakenly added to the question the </code> tag.

I have looked the code with firebug, then I saw the content of the page that i loaded in IFrame warped with <PRE> tag.

Like this

<pre>
"<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PressRelease.aspx.cs" Inherits="MBLMFC_PressRelease" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmPR" runat="server">
        ......
    </form>
</body>
</html>"</pre>

Thank You

Comment: <PRE> tag was automatically added. I don't know why.

Comment: Why do you have `runat="server"` on your `<iframe>` element?

Comment: <iframe id="frameNews" name="framePressRelease" runat="server" class="iframe" src="PressRelease.aspx"
                                    frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Yes I have

Comment: I have removed the runat="server". But still the same result.
Thank you.